# Как добавить в TableLayoutPanel новую строку и в нее добавить кнопку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как динамически, по нажатию кнопки например, добавить строку в System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel и в эту строку добавить кнопку.

**UPDATE:** Сейчас для добавления используется следующий код:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
this.SuspendLayout();

tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = ++this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size.Height + 100);
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button(), 0, i);
}

this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
this.ResumeLayout(false);

this.Refresh();

int j = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
```

Comment: Что в эту строку? Заинтриговали прям.

Comment: Как динамически по нажатию кнопки например добавлять строку в System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel и в эту строку добавить кнопку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить строку достаточно увеличить [`RowCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
tableLayoutPanel.RowCount++;
```

Добавить компонент в заданную ячейку можно с помощью [`TableLayoutControlCollection.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
//получение или создание кнопки
Button button = new Button();
//какая-то инициализация кнопки
//...
//Добавляем кнопку в первую (0) колонку последней строки
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button, 0, tableLayoutPanel.RowCount-1);
```

P.S. В Visual Studio можно построить нужный интерфейс, а потом в файле `ИмяФормы.designer.cs` посмотреть какой дизайнер сгенерировал код.

Comment: я вот так делаю, но кнопка не переносится в новую строку.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Вы не добавляете кнопку в новую строку, а в строку № i (от 0 до 2): `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button(), 0, i);` Замените `i` на `tableLayoutPanel.RowCount-1` (номер последней строки)

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Еще `ResumeLayout(false)` замените на `ResumeLayout(true)`

Answer (score 0):

я вот так добавляю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DynamicAddControls_CS
{
    public partial class Form1:Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void button1_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = ++this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size.Height + 100);
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
                this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button(), 0, i);
            }

            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

            this.Refresh();

            int j = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Новую информацию по вопросу нужно добавлять в сам вопрос.